# SQL Server 2008R2 Finding the max column from a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like below

```
A     B     C      D   
10   14    14     13
12   11    16     15
```

and my query should retrieve the answer like below:

```
E
14
16
```

How can I write a query to display it?

Comment: Do number of columns are fixed? i.e. only 4? Also What you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes the number of columns are fix. only 4 column(A,B,C,D)

Comment: [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/007764d0-4a2d-4227-a4db-21fce471fbb3/how-to-get-max-value-from-a-row](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/007764d0-4a2d-4227-a4db-21fce471fbb3/how-to-get-max-value-from-a-row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create Table #sample (
                [col1] int ,
                [col2] int ,
                [col3] int ,
                [col4] int 
);

INSERT INTO #sample 
(A, B, C, D)
VALUES
(10, 14, 14, 13),
(12, 11, 16, 15);

--Solution
select *, Row_Number() Over (Order By getdate()) Rid into #temp From #sample

Declare @Cols as Varchar(max)
Set @Cols=''
select @Cols = @Cols + ',[' + name + ']' from tempdb..syscolumns where id=object_id('tempdb..#temp')
and name <> 'Rid'

Select @Cols = Right(@Cols,len(@Cols)-1)
exec ('Select Rid,Max(val) maxval from #temp t
                                                Unpivot(val For data in (' + @Cols + ')) as Upvt
                                Group by Rid')

Drop table #temp
Drop table #sample
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case, brute force is the most efficient method.  Painful to type, but fastest:

```
select (case when A >= B and A >= C and A >= D then A
             when B >= C and B >= D then B
             when C >= D then C
             else D
        end) E
from t;
```

Comment: **Logic**.You can have multiple Query for same output SQL, but at the end of the day is all about logic, that is efficient. **`:)`**

Comment: You could run into complications when some of the columns are null, although it may not be possible

Comment: I edit it to save a problem if some of the columns are null, you have to put a ISNULL method to all columns references

Comment: @t-clausen.dk . . . You make a good point.  The OP does not mention `NULL` values  in either the question or the sample data.  I don't want to add in the code to handle them, unless that is actually part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for MS-Sqlserver 2005+:

Edit: as @hvd suggested

```
declare @t table(A int, B int, C int, D int)
insert @t values(10,14, 14, 13),(12,11, 16, 15)

select y.E from @t
cross apply
(
select max(E) E from
(
select a as E
union all
select b
union all
select c
union all
select d
)x 
)y
```

Result:

```
E
14
16
```

Comment: You don't need `cross apply` here, you can just put that in the `select` part of the query: `select (select top 1 E from (...) sub order by E desc) as E from table`. You can also use `max(E)` instead of `top 1 E order by E desc`.

Comment: @hvd I agree, max would have been better. Not sure what you mean by the first part.

Comment: I mean I would write it like http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18767. Aside from the table variable (which is for demonstration only), this is far more standard SQL while still working the same way.

Comment: @hvd in this example your senario would work, but if you need to refer to the value elsewhere in the query you are screwed. So I prefer using cross apply for this

Comment: You aren't screwed if you need to refer to it elsewhere in the query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18769 But personal preference is a valid reason for continuing to use `cross apply`, so don't take this as an objection. :)